# how to cast varchar with 3 numbers after comma to float type PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a varchar type where each value looks like

```
539,000
153,300
55,300
752,500
4410,000
```

I need change column type with number format

I tried use to_number but it is not working

Comment: Please make clear if at the shown values the comma is the German decimal separator (153,300 -> 153.3) or it is the thousand separator (153,300 -> 153300)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case your text representation is a German decimal value (comma is decimal separator):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=afc9cdede2b4e610b866230cdd24642a)

Replace comma with dot and simply cast into float:

```
SELECT replace('123,456', ',', '.')::float
```

---

In case the comma separates the thousand groups you need to use the `G` formatter, which describes this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fa74db698f0b92ca91dc0f7b8696a39d)

```
SELECT to_number('123,456', 'FM999G999')
```

`FM` supresses leading blanks and zeros, so even smaller number would work:

```
SELECT to_number('56', 'FM999G999')
```

Comment: I have executed this query

alter table orders alter column price type float
using replace(price, ',', '.')::float

but my numbers became like this

http://joxi.ru/J2b6Ov0F0wkJd2

Comment: Ehm... is the comma your thousand separator or the german decimal separator?

Comment: @Viktor added a second solution if the comma is the thousand separator instead of the comma separator

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have German numeric configuration set and use `to_number`:

```
SHOW lc_numeric;

 lc_numeric 
------------
 de_DE.utf8
(1 row)

SELECT to_number('539,000', '99999D000');

 to_number 
-----------
   539.000
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter like this

`ALTER COLUMN my_column TYPE float USING replace(my_column, ',','.')::float`

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2ff308849d986d26637a011102bb752c